# Removing "Ads by SpeedCheck" malware?

Tags: windows-7, malware-removal

Does anyone have a method to remove the "Ads by Speedcheck" malware?  My mom has it and it completely crippled her computer.  I googled it and just got a bunch of sites (ironically) that were short on info but big on ads.  No "legit" hits (such as SE) came back.  The one blog I did find that didn't look like an obvious ad trap gave instructions that didn't work.

I should probably just smoke the HD and start from scratch, but if anyone knows of a tried and true method I'd like to hear it.

She's using Win 7, which probably makes a difference if your suggestion is manual.

Comment: Malwarebytes use that

Comment: malwaretips.com is reliable. See [Remove “Ads by SpeedChecker” virus (Easy Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/speedchecker-removal/)

Answer (score 10):

Never trust removal tools to get rid of a virus, trust them to tell you have a virus, wipe the drive, re-install the OS, re-install your programs, and restore your data from backups.

However if you would prefer to use a virus removal tool, try [Comodo Cleaning Essentials](https://www.comodo.com/business-security/network-protection/cleaning_essentials.php), or [Comodo Rescue Disc](http://www.comodo.com/business-security/network-protection/rescue-disk.php) (which is a bootable version of Comodo Cleaning Essentials). It's free, and will scan for and remove anything it finds, it also has a killswitch if you run into trouble. It must be updated before you can use it, because the virus database isn't included, it's downloaded after. Comodo Cleaning Essentials does not require installation, just extract it from the .zip archive, and double click to run it.

[image: CCE Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I can see you're off to a great start here. Just so you know, I've edited your answer a bit to integrate your links into the text and display the image properly. If you need help with formatting, the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/formatting) has more information. I hope you enjoy all that [se] has to offer. Once again, welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a thread going on the Malwarebytes forum about this same issue - also with my mom's computer. I've tried several scanning tools, which found and removed a bunch of stuff, but the Ads by Speedcheck remain.

https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/160140-help-removing-ads-by-speedcheck/